# How to load only the children categories that belong to the current product (magento)

Tags: php, loops, magento, magento-1.9

I want to show  a list of categories a product belongs to, top categories and subcategories.

I figured out how to load the correct topcategories, but when I loop the subcats (children categories) it loads ALL subcats of that topcategory, not the categories that the product falls under.

Example:

[image]

Like you can see it loads a ton of subcategories, but only the ones with the red stripe are subcategories that the product falls under.

How can I make sure it only show those under their topcategories?

My code:

```
$currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
  $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
 ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
 //  ->addFieldToFilter('level',2)
 ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
 ->addIsActiveFilter();

  $out = "<ul>";
  foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
      $out .= "<li>";
      $out .= "<b><a href='".$cat->getUrl()."'>".$cat->getName()."</a></b>";
      $out .="<ul class='sub'>";
      $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
      // ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $cat->getCategoryIds())
      ->load($cat->getId())
      ->getChildrenCategories();
          foreach($children as $child){
              $out .="<li><a href='".$child->getUrl()."'>".$child->getName()."</a></li>";
          }
          $out .="</ul>";
      $out .= "</li>";
  }
  $out .= "</ul>";
  echo $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop check if category has product or not. `if($cat->getProductCount()){..}` and same thing for `$child`

```
$currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
//  ->addFieldToFilter('level',2)
->addAttributeToSelect('url')
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
->addIsActiveFilter();

$out = "<ul>";
foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
    if($cat->getProductCount()){
      $out .= "<li>";
      $out .= "<b><a href='".$cat->getUrl()."'>".$cat->getName()."</a></b>";
      $out .="<ul class='sub'>";
      $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
      // ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $cat->getCategoryIds())
      ->load($cat->getId())
      ->getChildrenCategories();
          foreach($children as $child){
            if($child->getProductCount()){
              $out .="<li><a href='".$child->getUrl()."'>".$child->getName()."</a></li>";
            }
          }
          $out .="</ul>";
      $out .= "</li>";
}
}
$out .= "</ul>";
echo $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try my code, It will work.

```
<?php
    $currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach ($currentCatIds as $categoryid) {
            $sub_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryid)->getChildrenCategories();
            foreach ($sub_categories as $category) {
                $cat_details = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-15 col-xs-4">
                        <div class="catImage">
                            <a href="<?php echo $cat_details->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $cat_details->getName(); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media', array('_secure' => true)) . 'catalog/category/' . $cat_details->getThumbnail(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat_details->getName(); ?>"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="title">
                            <a href="<?php echo $cat_details->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $cat_details->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $cat_details->getName(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
            }
    }
?>
```